# Вопрос по структуре html-файлов

Tags: html

Сейчас работаю над созданием сайта, где будет размещаться манга. Каждая глава - отдельный html-файл. Как итог, у меня около сотни этих файлов. Это нормально?
https://github.com/tfoxs/tfoxs
Если есть предложения, буду рад.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Смотря что вы считаете нормальным. Если Вас интересует, как это сделать эффективно и правильно, тогда вам нужно использовать параметризованные GET запросы для доступа к каждой главе. А уже по значению параметра вытаскивать из БД нужные данные.

Comment: js, так понимаю..?

Comment: В том числе может использоваться и он.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант

1. файл один с подгрузкой нужной манги/главы манги
2. что именно подгружать передаётся как параметр, но не в явном виде, типа `manga.php?id=123`, а именно в виде названия файла `manga123.html`, а сервер уже название файла преобразует в нужный запрос и в неявном виде передаёт для обработки

Comment: Я новичок в этом. Можно пример или видео урок/ открытый код/пример? Спасибо

Comment: вы только должны понимать - это уже из серии серверной (бэкэндовой) части, а не клиентской (фронтендовой), т.е. у вас должен быть и сервер (ну или место на сервере на котором у вас будет такая возможность), если вы во всем новичок, тогда лучше пока на клиентской части сосредоточиться

Comment: Тогда оставлю так. Спасибо

Comment: серверную часть вы потом легко сможете нарастить, главное изначально продумайте универсальность какую-то